# Data visualization multiple choices multiple condition conditions

Tags: data, visualization

Say I have a element that base on a certain condition (1, 2, 3 or 4), it chooses a decision (A,B or C). What diagrams can be used to present this data if I have more than one thousand elements so that:

- One can see what are the most popular selection based on a particular condition.
- Easy to identify which element change their decision if the condition is changed.

Any ideas? Any suggestion or hint would be very much appreciated!

[image]

UPDATE: I have implement parallel coordinates (suggested by @Oxbowerce), but for instance for condition3, one cannot see how much of elements have chosen the different decisions. Also, for instance from condition1 to condition2, how much have moved from decision "2" to decision "1"? it is not visible from the plot.

More suggestions will be very welcome!

[image]

Comment: Have a look at using a [parallel coordinates plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates), preferable an interactive one as this would allow you to interactive select based on certain conditions.

Comment: @Oxbowerce thanks for your suggestion, I have updated my post including your comment.

Comment: Another thing is that with parallel coordinates, it gives the impression that the conditions are sequential or progressive in time, but these conditions are independent and there is not a particular order to follow.